# Parent view doesn't follow its height

Tags: react-native

I have a simple view with two children. I expect the parent view to be of height 80 dip and both children having the same height. But both children are hidden. What is wrong with my understanding?

[image]

```
export default class SignUpSignInScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 80,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 1,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, flex: 1 }}> +91</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
              borderColor: 'gray',
              borderWidth: 1,
              flex: 1,
            }}
            placeholder="Enter your phone number"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's not hidden set text color which will be visible to check that it is rendering or not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `View` or remove `flex:1` from the second view.
Expo [link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/laughing-crackers)